# Android Error/Crash checking plugin for Android IDE

Tags: android, debugging, compiler-errors

I wanted to know if there is any plugin similar to Android Lint which would tell me about the android code errors and warnings to avoid any future memory leaks or crashes.

Android Lint is not solving my problem. Is there any other tool for the same

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing which lint is unable to figure out?

Comment: You can use Leak Canary.

Comment: Lint is not giving me any suspicious code. And the app is failing at runtime due to memory leaks and other crashes

Comment: Lint can't know every possible problem. If it was so intelligent, we wouldn't need testing at all. Instead of looking for a magical plugin, which will show you all errors (which is impossible by definition), post your code and error here

Answer (score 0):

You can check these tools:
[checkstye](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)
[find bugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)